# Magento 1.9 Product page is not visible for logged in customers

Tags: magento-1.9, products, login, product-page

**Logged In customers** couldn't view the **product page** but they **can view the category page**.

`No issue with the Non-logged in or guest customers`, they can view both the product page and category page.

Comment: Is there any third party module or custom module installed to restrict access to the product page?

Comment: No. haven't added anything.

Comment: I suggest enabling profiler and trace the path. It will be easy to debug that way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some error occurs for a logged in customer.
Please edit the following file:

> Magento_root/index.php

Please find the following lines of code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and replace these by the following code:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Please reload a product page as logged in customer, hope you will see an error causing the issue.
Please **do not forget** to revert back changes in the edited file after check.